# Python: Create annotation space above the graph in Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I would like to create additional space for annotations within the plot (see green area in attached image).
At the moment, the y-axis defines my height of the plot. Can I push the plot beyond the y.max limit/hide the y-axis after a certain point (marked red in the image)?
I try to avoide the axis reaching into the 'comment section' (green).

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxlFV.png)

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried in a code snippet.

Comment: A very similar question has been asked and answered before. Everything you need is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913366/plotly-how-to-annotate-a-point-outside-the-plot-itself/60921025#60921025)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled on this question after answering another of your questions and thought it was interesting.

Is this what you're after?

[image]

#### Key Elements:

The key elements of creating the elevated annotation are:

- `xref` and `yref` are set to `'paper'`, thus using the graph's  **background** for `xy` coordinates rather than graph data values
- Using > 1.00 for the `y` positioning
- `layout['margin']` **top** set to a value to create a top margin, thus pushing the graph area down

#### Sample Code:

It's really much simpler than it looks.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import iplot

# Create the dataset.
n = 360
x = np.arange(n)
y = [np.sin(i*(np.pi/180)) for i in range(n)]

# Plot the sin wave.
data = []
data.append({'x': x,
             'y': y})

# Create the annotations.
notes = []
notes.append({'text': ('An annotation at the top of the graph.<br><br>'
                       'And some more rambling text to take up some '
                       'more space on the graph to represent<br>'
                       'a longer annotation, just because we can.<br><br>'
                       'And one more for good measure.'),
              'x': 0.00,
              'y': 1.60,
              'xref': 'paper',
              'yref': 'paper',
              'showarrow': False,
              'align': 'left'})
notes.append({'text': 'Elevated Graph Annotation Example',
              'x': 0.00,
              'y': 1.15,
              'xref': 'paper',
              'yref': 'paper', 
              'showarrow': False,
              'font': {'size': 18}})

# Setup the layout.
layout = {}
layout['annotations'] = notes
layout['margin'] = {'t': 175}

# Plot the data. (May also use `plot` rather than `iplot`)
iplot({'data': data, 'layout': layout})
```

#### Note:

You'll have to create your own graph title (rather than relying on the `title` parameter available in `layout`) as you'll need to position the graph title yourself.  Otherwise the automatic title and annotations will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations have **x** and **y** as parameters. If your **y** exceeds the max y in your plot, the space will extend above to reach **y**.

For example, adding the following annotation with y=32, the text lands inside of the plot (max y is at around 50):

```
plot.add_annotation(x=30, y=32,
            text="Text annotation with arrow",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=1)
```

[Plot with annotation with y < max y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndtND.png)

And changing y=32 to y=52 the plot looks like this:

[Plot with annotation with y > max y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmE4o.png)

As you see, the max y in the plot increased to over 60 to allow the annotation to find its place