# ggplotly removes legend superscript and caption in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to create an interactive plot with a `ggplot` object via `ggplotly`. The `ggplot` plots fine but `ggplotly` removes the `superscript` from the legend and also the `caption` of the plot.

How can I fix this?

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(plotly)
    
        # df
        Pollutant_1 = c(2.5, 3.5, 1.5, 7.5)
        Pollutant_2 = c(4, 1.3, 2.5, 3.5)
        Year = c(2000, 2001, 2004, 2003)
        
        df = data.frame(Year , Pollutant_1,  Pollutant_2)
        
            # Plot 
            # Make a legend vector
            legend = expression(Pollutant_1~"(ug/m)"^{3},
                                      Pollutant ~"Matter 2.5 (ug/m)"^3)
            
            gg = ggplot(df, aes(x = Year)) +
              geom_line(aes(y = Pollutant_1, color = Pollutant_1),size = 1) +
              geom_point(aes(y = Pollutant_1)) +
              scale_color_discrete(labels = legend) +
              geom_line(aes(y = Pollutant_2, color = Pollutant_2), size = 1) +
              geom_point(aes(y = Pollutant_2)) +
                               labs(x = "Date",
                                    y = "Concentration", 
                                    title = "Title",
                                    color = "Legend",
                                    caption = str_wrap("big caption."))

# Interactive 
ggplotly(gg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue.

One workaround for short captions is found here: [plotly adding a source or caption to a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103559/plotly-adding-a-source-or-caption-to-a-chart).  For the (MANY) plotly annotation options see [this documentation](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/annotations/).

For longer captions, you'll need to set up some margins to write in.  Instructions here: [Python: Create annotation space above the graph in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064217/python-create-annotation-space-above-the-graph-in-plotly)

Would love to know if someone has a better approach.