# Annotation not found outside plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I have a graph that looks like this:

where I want to add some text towards the left bottom side of the plot, something similar to the text at the bottom here, but for me on my left or right side of the graph.

[image]

I searched on stack and found many solutions, even one specific to the graph shown,however none work for me. My current code is below, where the annotation does not display on my plot.

```
data1= final_api.query("info_title=='JupyterHub'").sort_values(by=['commitDate'])
data1['Year-Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['Year-Month']) 
data1['Commit-growth'] = data1['commits'].cumsum()
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()


fig = px.scatter(data1, x='Year-Month', y='Commit-growth', color='major_version', text='Commit-growth')

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines',
                         x=data1["Year-Month"],
                         y=data1["Commit-growth"],
                         line_color='black',
                         line_width=1,
                         line_shape='hvh',
                         showlegend=False
                       )
             )

for _,row in data1.iterrows():
    fig.add_annotation(
        go.layout.Annotation(
            x=row["Year-Month"],
            y=row["Commit-growth"],
            text=row['info_version'],
            showarrow=False,
            align='center',
            yanchor='bottom',
            yshift=5,
            textangle=-10)
    )


note = 'NYSE Trading Days After Announcement<br>Source:<a href="https://www.nytimes.com/"">The NY TIMES</a> Data: <a href="https://www.yahoofinance.com/">Yahoo! Finance</a>'
fig.add_annotation(
    showarrow=False,
    text=note,
    font=dict(size=5), 
    xref='x domain',
    x=0.5,
    yref='y domain',
    y=-0.5
    )

fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white',title_text=' Version Change in Jupyter Hub API by commits',title_x=0.5,
                  xaxis_title='Year-Month', yaxis_title='Number of Commits', yaxis_range=[0, 400],height=760, width=1600, xaxis_range=['2016-06-01', '2021-04-01'])
fig.update_traces(textposition="bottom right", showlegend=False,marker_size=10,marker_line_width=2, marker_line_color='black')

fig.show()
```

Any help on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913366/how-to-annotate-a-point-outside-the-plot-itself/60921025#60921025) a try?

Comment: I tried, inverting both, but one places it right at top and the other places it on the right side in the middle of the graph, I have been trying to adjust the dimensions by hit and trial but the last they go is to the end of the plot on the left hand side, which I want to be outside of the plot

Comment: update: i was able to figure it out using plotly chart studio to get an approx for the numbers, i could not get it to the bottom left, but upper left is aligned which works as well for me. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: figured how to do it by myself

Add another annotation like this, although it gives the text at the upper left corner of the graph,works for me. Just add this code instead of the previous annotation code in the question,the rest of the code remains the same.These dimensions work for the particular alignment mentioned.

```
fig.add_annotation(
    showarrow=False,
    text="23 paths over 450 updates",
    font=dict(size=15),
    xref='paper',
    x=0.014,
    yref='paper',
    y=1.077
    )
```

Comment: So what you were missing in your previous attempts was probably `xref='paper'` and `yref='paper'`?

Comment: yes those and the dimensions in general, it needed quite a bit trial and error to align them.